# difference between LWT/Paxos queries's timestamp and normal queries' timestamp in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, timestamp, cql

when using cassandra, if you execute the following two cql, the second one will not success.

```
insert into job_info (id, create_time) values (5be224c6-8231-11e7-9619-9801b2a97471, 0) IF NOT EXISTS;
insert into job_info (id, create_time) values (5be224c6-8231-11e7-9619-9801b2a97471, 1);
```

The keyspace and the table is like this:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE scheduler WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'}  AND durable_writes = true;

CREATE TABLE scheduler.job_info (
    id timeuuid PRIMARY KEY,
    create_time int
) with caching = {'keys':'ALL', 'rows_per_partition':'NONE'};
```

I posted this issue on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13767, and the commant said that:

> You're mixing LWT/Paxos queries ({{IF NOT EXISTS}}, which deals with
>   timestamp in its own way, with "normal" queries, and that is known to
>   lead to unpredictable results in term of ordering (what happens here
>   is not that the 2nd insert fails, it's that it gets assigned a
>   timestamp than is lower than the 1st query and is thus ignored). Long
>   story short, don't mix LWT/Paxos queries with other queries (at least
>   on the same partition) and you'll avoid issue.

My question is, what is the difference between the LWT/Paxos queries and "normal" queries' timestamp?

The first cql and the second cql can be executed with a interval of many seconds, but the second one still not success. SO , is it really a problem caused by timestamp?

Comment: If the two query executed from a single client (cqlsh/driver) synchronously. Your latest value should be `1`

Comment: Is the two query executed from different client ? If yes then include it in your question.

Comment: Quite startling that even with _several seconds_ between the LWT and the normal query the write timestamp on the LWT query is _still_ later than the normal one.